# How do I execute a command-line application built with Xcode?

Tags: xcode6

I'm building a small command-line utility (not an app) with xcode. All I want to do is the equivalent of a *gcc -o name*, and I'm completely stumped. I can compile just fine in xcode, and execute the result *inside of xcode*,  but I can't for the life of me find the executable image anywhere on the disk. There's nothing at all executable in the .../DerivedData folder, for example. How do I tell Xcode to create a stand-alone executable image (that I can launch from a Terminal window) and put it in a known location?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. When you select the Product for the application, make sure that the application is set to Unix Executable (it defaults to something else). The full path to the product is displayed further down in the dialog.